# Magento 1.9.2 - getRequest()->getParams returning with empty array

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, data

I'm working on a legacy Magento site which has a custom contact form modelled on https://inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/. At some point in the past few months, this has stopped working. In those few months, the site has had update patches and has been moved to a new server.

Here is a snippet of the phtml form:

```
<form id="form-validate" name="simple_contact_form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('company-companycontact/') ?>index/sendemail" class="f-form" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />

        <div class="fieldset">
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?php echo $this->getSuccessUrl() ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?php echo $this->getErrorUrl() ?>" />
        <h2 class="legend"><?php echo $this->__('Personal Information') ?></h2>
        <ul class="form-list">
            <li class="fields">
                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getFormData())->setForceUseCustomerAttributes(true)->toHtml() ?>
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="email_address" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email_address" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                    </div>
            </li>


    <div class="buttons-set">


                    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" class="f-btn f-float-right"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>


            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-validate', true);
                <?php if($this->getShowAddressFields()): ?>
                new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'zip');
                <?php endif; ?>
            //]]>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And a snippet of the controller (I've removed the email processing logic, be rest assured that all works).

```
<?php
class Company_CompanyContact_IndexController extends 
  Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
     {
 public function indexAction()
 {
    //Get current layout state
    $this->loadLayout();   

    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        'Mage_Core_Block_Template',
        'inchoo.simple_contact',
        array(
            'template' => 'contacts/trade_registration.phtml'
        )
    );

    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
    //$this->getLayout()->getBlock('right')->insert($block, 'catalog.compare.sidebar', true);

    $this->_initLayoutMessages('core/session');

    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function sendemailAction()
{ 
    //Fetch submited params
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    Mage::log($params, null, 'trade.log', true);

            $formInfo = "";
            $formInfo .= "<strong>First Name:</strong> " . $params['firstname'] . "<br>";
            $formInfo .= "<strong>Surname:</strong> " . $params['lastname'] . "<br>";
            $formInfo .= "<strong>Email</strong>: " . $params['email'] . "<br>";

    }
  }

  ?>
```

When I try to dump the $params in a log, I just get and empty array. Equally, if I try `$this->getRequest()->getParam('firstname')` or `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('firstname');`, both values return null.

Did anything change in recent patches or PHP7 which could break this function?

Thanks